# How to stop PyCharm from pre-pending a space on paste?

Tags: pycharm

PyCharm (2016.2 Community Edition) pre-pends a ' ' (space character) to strings on paste. So you select 'abc' and see ' abc' inserted after pasting. This is probably some sort of 'smart' behavior; but I could not find a config entry for this.

I would like to know how to turn this behavior off.

(I want the paste operation to put in exactly what I copied)

**EDIT**

This behavior must be a fluke; now I cannot reproduce it, even in the same project (and I am quite happy about it). I did not make any configuration changes. So this is perhaps a bug. And yes, I tested this carefully and the phenomenon was definitely there in the first place (it was driving me nuts for a whole day).

Comment: Are you *sure*? For me it pastes exactly what I copied, no spaces added. Did you try copying from different sources (the editor, browser, etc.)? Maybe it is a hidden space that you overlooked.

Comment: I tested this carefully; I was *not* selecting a leading space, and yet it was added at paste (and immediately highlighted in pink as non-conforming whitespace). It's been annoying me for the whole day yesterday. BUT today I cannot reproduce this. So, as long as this does not recur, all is fine. I will edit the question to point out it is a fluke behavior, possibly a bug.